# Why is my version of Gimp missing the palette to gradient tool?

Tags: gimp, gradient, palette

For some reason my version of gimp is missing certain features/buttons

I am trying to create a gradient from a palette but when I right click on the palette it is missing the option to do what is suggested in this image

[image: Buttons that should be there]

On a documentation page it suggests

[image: Documentation Suggestion]

But the link is just to the Python homepage and I can't find any other details anywhere

What should I do to get these features?

I am running Gimp 2.10.8 on Ubuntu 19.04 downloaded using the package manager

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. What version of GIMP are you using?  Where did you download it from?  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am running Gimp 2.10.8 on Ubuntu 19.04 downloaded using the package manager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On recent Ubuntu (since 18.04 at least, may be earlier) they made the Python support in Gimp optional. You can tell if your Gimp has Python support by looking at the bottom of the Filters menu that should have a `Python-fu` submenu alongside the `Script-fu` one. If it's not there you are missing Python.

You can install the Gimp python support using `sudo apt install gimp-python`.